# Geany - Python execution error: "is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: python, python-3.x, geany

I'm trying to run my scripts in Geany and get the following message:

```
"'C:\Users\Krishn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"
```

Please see my build configuration as below:

```
Compile - C:\Users\Krishn Patel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32 -m py_compile "%f"

Execute - C:\Users\Krishn Patel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32 "%f"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have a space in your windows user name`Krishn Patel`. You should escape that space by putting `^` behind it or putting the command between `"`.
https://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks

Comment: I tried "C:\Users\Krishn Patel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32 -m py_compile" "%f" and C:\Users\Krishn Patel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32" "%f" and get "        '"C:\Users\Krishn Patel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: Are you sure that python is installed and that path points to python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

Setting to default resolved the issue
    Exec : python "%f"